# python3-wheel installed, still using legacy 'setup.py' when installing dlib

Tags: docker, dlib, python-wheel, python-3.9

I've [forked](https://github.com/Amitie10g/zoneminder.machine.learning) [dlandon's **Zoneminder**](https://github.com/dlandon/zoneminder.machine.learning) project in order to build a Docker image using **Debian Bullseye** instead of Ubuntu, **for i386** (I'm installing it into a 32-bit mini PC).

Part of the requiriments is installing [`dlib`](https://pypi.org/project/dlib) (latest is 19.22.0). I've installed the required dependencies ([`python3-pip`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python3-pip), [`python3-setuptools`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python3-setuptools) and [`python3-wheel`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python3-wheel), as well as GCC and CMake).

When installing `dlib`, the terminal outputs:

```
Collecting dlib
  Downloading dlib-19.22.0.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib: started
    ...
```

The relevant part is (even with `python3-wheel` installed)

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
```

`dlib` builts successfully but takes a looong time to build, however. This happens with any packages supossed to use `wheel`.

I haven't found any (answered) questions about this specific issue, so, if there is something I missed, I would be told about that.

Everything is in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Amitie10g/zoneminder.machine.learning/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `pip install wheel` in your env